# Does the affirmation "Lord is God" in Deut. 4:35 refer to God in the plural or singular sense?

Tags: deuteronomy, 1-kings, names-of-god, 2-samuel, trinity

The OT often states; Lord (Jehovah) God (Elohim) in sequence.

- Deut. 4:35; LORD (Jehovah) he is God (Elohim).
- Deut. 4:39; that the LORD (Jehovah) he is God (Elohim).
- 2 Sam. 7:22; LORD (Jehovah) God (Elohim).
- 1 Kings 8:60; LORD (Jehovah) is God (Elohim).

In breaking these down, LORD was always translated Jehovah (Strongs 3068 Yhovah), and God translated Elohim (Strongs 430 Elohiym).
Elohim is in the plural form. I accepted this as describing God's plurality, such as in the Trinity, because had "God" in these verses meant singular, I thought it would have stated Elowahh (Strongs 433) and not Elohim.

I was then told that the reason this plural noun Elohim is translated into other languages as a singular noun is because it's being used with a singular verb.
Comparable to saying "Ants is here to stay" instead of "Ants are here to stay". It turns this plural word ("ants") into a proper noun."

I would like a clarification: is Jehovah being described as a singular God with plurality when stating Elohim, or does it actually mean Jehovah in the singular sense and no plurality.

Comment: Other questions of plurality of Elohim: [1](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/in-genesis-2013-why-is-elohim-with-a-plural-verb-translated-god-rather-than-go), [2](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8395/should-the-word-elohim-in-psalm-85-be-translated-into-gods-angels-or-god), [3](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/why-is-elohim-translated-as-god-rather-than-gods-in-genesis-11), [4](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/in-genesis-2013-why-is-elohim-with-a-plural-verb-translated-god-rather-than-go/12992#12992)

Comment: It;s not that LORD translated into Jehovah. The original word is Jehovah/Yahweh. However, somebody REPLACE (not translate) the word Yahweh into LORD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if the phrase is properly "YHVH is God" or "YHVH is Gods" then clearly it is "YHVH is God". The form of a word does not always indicate number just as it doesn't always indicate gender. From what I understand "youth" in Hebrew is plural in form but is singular. Also "lord" (ADONAI) is plural in form but is singular:

"...YHVH said to my ADONAI sit at my right hand..." (Ps 110:1)

Obviously he is speaking to his singular Messiah. The Jews - and the early Christians - were strict monotheists.

Comment: Adonai is not plural. Nor is it "obvious" that Ps 110 refers to the Messiah. But have we not had this same question many times before?

Comment: Actually, Adonai is the plural form of ADON:   http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Names_of_G-d/Adonai/adonai.html   It is plural in word form but not in meaning.

Comment: @fdb yes, it has been asked many times